# Filling multidimensional array from JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following code that is intended to fill a global array with JSON object

```
// global arrays declaration
var sectionL=[1,5,3,7,5,4,3,3,4,4,6,6,3,5,5,1];
var sectionsTitle=new Array(16);
var sectionsContent=new Array(16);
for(var i=0; i<sectionL.length;i++){
  sectionsTitle[i]=new Array(sectionL[i]);
  sectionsContent[i]=new Array(sectionL[i]);
}
var country = new Array(4);
 for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
 country[i]=new Array();  
 country[i][2]=sectionsTitle;// allocate see above 
 country[i][3]=sectionsContent;// allocate see above
//////////////////////////////////////

function getCountries(data){
 $.each(data['countries'], function (k,val){
 country[k][0]=val['title']; // store the title
 country[k][1]=val['id']; // store the id to send to the JSON

  $.getJSON(baseURL+country[k][1]+'&callback=?',function(data ){
  console.log("k=>"+k+"  id=>"+country[k][1]); // just to check if k is passed
   for(var i=0;i<1;i++){
    index=i+1;
      for(var j=0;j<1;j++){
         country[k][2][i][j]=data['result']['sectionTitles']['section'+index+'.'+j+'.title']; // fill the array with the content
      }
   }
 });
});



console.log(country);
```

returns

```
[Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4]]
k=>0  id=>9
k=>1  id=>29
k=>3  id=>31
k=>4  id=>12
k=>2  id=>7
```

Problem: the values of the arrays are overwritten and only show the last. 
I suspect a closure  issue, but I am stuck. Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: your for loop, conditions: ```i<1``` and ```j<1```?

Comment: thanks, not an issue, I just wanted to test for the first line since I have some empty sections.

Comment: ok, what variable values are getting overwritten, bit more explanation on that part

Comment: country[k][2][0][0] are all the same and correspond to k=2 , (the last to be called)

Comment: check if the below solution works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I think the problem lies in

```
 country[i][2]=sectionsTitle;// allocate see above 
 country[i][3]=sectionsContent;// allocate see above
```

you are assigning same objects to everything, so all refer to the same object, hence the problem, one solution might be...

```
...

     country[i][2]=getSectionDetails(sectionL);// allocate see above 
     country[i][3]=getSectionDetails(sectionL);// allocate see above
...

function getSectionDetails(data){
    var details=[]
    data.forEach(function(v){ details.push([v]);});
    return details;
}
```

**Previous**:

<strike>I am assuming the problem is `$.getJSON` shares the variable `k` with others, my solution would be...</strike>

```
function getCountries(data){
    var url;
     $.each(data['countries'], function (k,val){
         country[k][0]=val['title']; // store the title
         country[k][1]=val['id']; // store the id to send to the JSON
         url = baseURL+country[k][1]+'&callback=?';
         $.getJSON(url, onJSONData.bind({k:k, url: url}));  
    });
}


function onJSONData(data){
    var k = this.k;
    console.log("k=>",k,"  url=>",this.url, 'data =>', data); // just to check if k is passed
    country[k][2][0][0]=data.result.sectionTitles.section1[0].title; // fill the array with the content            
}
```

Comment: still same issue see image [link](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=205w01&s=8#.VO15V7OUc4R)

Comment: thanks, the data object inside onJSONData is correct. but the array country is still filled with the last object.  Could be an asynchronous problem?

Comment: forgot to ask, where exactly are you checking the ```country``` value, the place where the values are checked in your question, json call would not even have finished by then.

Comment: Yes, I tried 'console.log(country)' inside 'onJSONData()' after the for loop, and in 'getCountries' after the    '$.getJSON' call.  same results in both case. but i noticed sometimes the output changes. see [link] (http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2m79emr&s=8#.VO2KErOUc4Q), there is myanmar where it used to be vietnam..

Comment: Hi mido22, I have another question, how would you fill sectionL from the JSON?

Comment: @user4604233 what do you mean by fill?

Comment: var sectionL=[1,5,3,7,5,4,3,3,4,4,6,6,3,5,5,1];  the values are hard coded, but  they correspond to the length of the sectionTitles object. I'd like to get them from the JSON . I tried data['result']['sectionTitles'].length but it does not work since it is not an array..

Comment: try ```Object.keys(data['result']['sectionTitles']).length```

Comment: HI Mido, thanks a lot for your thorough help, I have opened a new question for my problem http://stackoverflow.com/q/28826035/4604233 If you have time please take a look!