# fill global array with JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a hard coded global  array that looks like

```
   //var sectionL=[1,5,3,7,7,4,5,3,4,3,6,6,4,5,4,1];
```

Instead I would like to fill that global array from JSON request
I tried with

```
var sectionL=[];

 function fillsectionL(){
 $.getJSON(baseURL+'&callback=?',function(data ){
 var len= Object.keys(data['result']['sectionL']).length;
    for(var i =0;i<len;i++){
      sectionL[i]=data['result']['sectionL'];
    }
});

}
```

I read about asynchronous and that the output will be fired before the code is executed. Is there a simple way to do something like

```
 sectionL=fillSection();
```

and have fillSection return an array?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to follow this link to learn how to work with javascript arrays.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

Answer (score 0):

The "getJSON" api you're using here (and indeed, all JS browser-based APIs for interacting with remote servers) is asynchronous. It happens "in the background" and calls your callback function when it's finished fetching data. If you have code that needs to run after this callback completes, you can try simply calling that code from within your callback, as the least complicated  way to get started.

Answer (score 0):

```
sectionL[i]=data['result']['sectionL'];
```

You can use Push method to fill array like that

```
sectionL.push(data['result']['sectionL']);


I don't know json format you received so i amused your received correct
```